# Correct usage of self in Python classes

Tags: python, class, self

In the example below, classes `AA` and `BB` are instantiated with params `a` and `b` and feature the `foo` method.  The only difference between classes `AA` and `BB` is that in the `AA` `foo` method, the intermediate variable `z` is prefixed with the class instance reference `self` while in class `BB` it is not.  What is the correct methodology here?  When should `self` be used within class methods and when should it not be used?  I've always been confused by this!

```
class AA:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def foo(self):
        self.z = self.a + self.b
        return self.z * self.a

class BB:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def foo(self):
        z = self.a + self.b
        return z * self.a
```

Comment: If you don't need to preserve the value of `z` as an instance attribute, the second form (where `z` is just a local variable) is fine.

Comment: That title is pretty vague. It might be better to switch it to something like "When should I assign an intermediate variable to the class instance in a method?" See [ask] for tips on writing a good title.

Comment: `self` refers to the instance. So you use it when you want to refer to the instance. It has **no special meaning** and is **just** a name for a parameter. All the magic happens when the method is called.

Comment: Note that lazily initialized attributes (assigned at unpredictable points after `__init__` is done) break [PEP 412: Key-sharing dictionaries](https://peps.python.org/pep-0412/); if you make a lot of these instances, the extra memory overhead of initializing late will hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Neither one is "correct" per se. It depends what you want to do: If you want to keep the value around, then you could assign it to the instance. If not, then don't.

Although, if you do assign it as a public instance attribute, you'll probably want to [set an initial value in `__init__()`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/357937/352138), like `None`.

Comment: Got it thanks, so really it is a question of whether the variable needs to be kept in memory for use elsewhere.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

the use of the self will appear when you initiate an object from the class, so in order that the object will have an access to the variable you need to use the self

```
class AA:
def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

def foo(self):
    self.z = self.a + self.b
    return self.z * self.a

class BB:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def foo(self):
        z = self.a + self.b
        return z * self.a
A = AA(1, 2)
A.foo()
print(A.z) # will print the value
B = BB(1, 2)
B.foo()
print(B.z) # will not print the value, "z" attribute is not defined
```